# How to filter HTML table data based on Gmail sign in users

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

[image]My Page consists of HTML table and top of that I have added a search button.
I used "Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()" to get Gmail sign in users email address . when users login /open the web app,  sign in users email address should input in the search bar and search function should run accordingly

[Smaple Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ElSP7aTrXLt4oan40POwFLjFBOie-FybrHPBx-DuhV8/edit?usp=sharing)[Webapp](https://script.google.com/a/teamcomputers.com/macros/s/AKfycbxbu-E-YP5Je1crqeaGkLC2RGFWtg8YB9Xg-zONW-I/dev)

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
   .evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  return html;
}



function getCurrentUserEmail()
{
  var email={'email':Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()};//returned as an object
  return email;
}

function getData() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('1ElSP7aTrXLt4oan40POwFLjFBOie-FybrHPBx-DuhV8')
      .getSheetByName("Sheet2")
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>

<body>

 <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
 
</nav>
</div>
</div>


<hr>
    <base target="_top">
    <!-- <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <script>
    $(function() {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(dispEmail)
      .getCurrentUserEmail();
     });//runs after dom is loaded
     function dispEmail(data)
     {
       $('.email').text(data.email);//put's email into h1 tag
     }
     console.log('My Code');
    </script>
  <div class="container">
    <font color="#440F89"><b>Your Requset and updated Status as Below</b></font>
   <!-- <input class="email" type="text" id="myInput" onchange="myFunction()" > -->
<span class="email" type="text" id="myInput" onchange="myFunction()" ></span>
   <hr>  
   </div>
<? var data = getData(); ?>
<div class="container">
<table id="myTable"class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed myTable">
<tr>
  <td class="bg-primary"><b>Requester Name</b></td>
  <td class="bg-primary"><b>Request Type</b></td>
  <td class="bg-primary"><b>Request For</b></td>
  <td class="bg-primary"><b>Short Description</b></td>
  <td class="bg-primary"><b>Business Reason for Request/Purpose</b></td>
  <td class="bg-primary"><b>Urgency</b></td>
  <td class="bg-primary"><b>SM Team Member(Assgined)</b></td>
  <td class="bg-primary"><b>Notes</b></td>
  <td class="bg-primary"><b>Resolution</b></td>
  <td class="bg-primary"><b>Status</b></td>
</tr>
  <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
    <tr>
      <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
        <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
      <? } ?>
    </tr>
  <? } ?>
</table>
</div>



<script>
function myFunction() {
//var input, filter, table, tr, td, i; "replaced with below tag"
  var span, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  //input = document.getElementById("myInput"); "replaced with below tag"
  span = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add if condition to check for the email address of the logged user while appending the table rows. Please refer the below code.

**code.gs**

```
function doGet() {

  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  template.email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}  

function getData() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
      .openById('1bDInWEbbdXOf6LbYC5UMQBCqGFEqpdhNjWsyUeCYTtw')
      .getSheetByName("Sheet2")
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues();
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>

<body>

 <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">

</nav>
</div>
</div>


<hr>
    <base target="_top">
   <div class="container">
    <font color="#440F89"><b>Your Requset and updated Status as Below</b></font>
   <input class="email" type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()" value="<?=email?>">
   <hr>  
   </div>
<? var data = getData(); ?>
<div class="container">
<table id="myTable"class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed myTable">
<tr>
  <td class="bg-primary"><b>Requester Name</b></td>
  <td class="bg-primary"><b>Request Type</b></td>
  <td class="bg-primary"><b>Request For</b></td>
  <td class="bg-primary"><b>Short Description</b></td>
  <td class="bg-primary"><b>Business Reason for Request/Purpose</b></td>
  <td class="bg-primary"><b>Urgency</b></td>
  <td class="bg-primary"><b>SM Team Member(Assgined)</b></td>
  <td class="bg-primary"><b>Notes</b></td>
  <td class="bg-primary"><b>Resolution</b></td>
  <td class="bg-primary"><b>Status</b></td>
</tr>
  <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    if(data[i][0].toUpperCase() !== email.toUpperCase()) {?>
    <tr style="display:none;">
      <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
        <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
      <? } ?>
    </tr>
  <? } else{ ?>
    <tr>
      <? for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) { ?>
        <td><?= data[i][j] ?></td>
      <? } ?>
    </tr>
  <?} }?>
</table>
</div>



<script>
function myFunction() {
  var span, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput"); 
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function getCurrentUserEmail() return just a string which is the email.

So in your dispEmail(data) function, data is just the string you returned.
When you want to display data.email it does not work as data is not a json but a string so your function must be :

```
function dispEmail(data)
     {
       $('.email').text(data);//put's email into h1 tag
     }
```

**Edit after 1st answer** :
To launch the filter function you have to add it in your success handler.

```
$(function() {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(dispEmail)
      .getCurrentUserEmail();
     });//runs after dom is loaded

function dispEmail(data)
     {
       $('.email').text(data);//put's email into h1 tag
       myFucntion();//To start filtering
     }
```

Stéphane

Comment: @Stéphane
I am able to input the email address in search box, but filter script is not working (refer the updated Image Snap)

Comment: I edited my answer. You have to run the myFunction after your add the email. Just call the function.